# Ignore blank cells in dynamic named range

Tags: excel

I have list with blanks and I cannot get the ever-so-popular dynamically named range formula to work:

```
=OFFSET(Tasks!$G$2,0,0,MATCH("*",Tasks!$G$2:$G$22,-1),1)
```

The data validation list I use it for is still showing all the blanks!

Please help and advise!

Many thanks

Comment: are the blanks within the data or at the end? if they're within it you're out of luck

Comment: why don't you just apply the filter on the column and remove "blanks" and then apply your formula...

Answer (score 0):

I can't understant what you really want/need.

If your list as blanks in between, so not sorted, you must use `MATCH` with 3rd argument `0`.

Then,

```
=OFFSET(Tasks!$G$2,0,0,MATCH("*",Tasks!$G$2:$G$22,0),1)
```

will return a range starting in cell $G$2 with a number of rows equal to the number of cells before first blank cell. Putting this in a single cell, will simply show cell $G$2 value.

What kind of use do you want for the range?

Comment: Yes, there are blanks in-between.  I'm using the named range for data validation. Basically I want a dropdown list in another sheet to show only tasks that are incomplete.  I tried using a pivot table, which worked perfectly, until I discovered that pivot tables can't updated once shared.

Comment: Not very beautiful, but you can add a column (`X` for example) accumulating non blank cells on `Tasks!G:G` (`X3` would be `=X2+IF(G2="";0;1)`). Then, in another area/sheet, create a column (`Y` for example)  with sequencial numbers and another (`Z` for example) matching row where number match 'X' column match number (`Z2` whould be `=OFFSET(Tasks!$G$2,0,MATCH(Y2,$Z$2:$Z$22,0)-1,1,1)`).